# Passing in an argument within a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing

I have a bash script that I use to call a java class and I pass two arguments to this java class. The first argument ($1) is the string that I pass and it contains someone's name. The second argument ($2) is the previous month as a two digit number (also passed in by the user).

So the java class is called like this:

```
 java -DCONFIG_DIR=... com.example.myapp.grades.gradingProcess $1 $2
```

However, now, I don't want the user to pass in the second argument and instead, I want the script to determine the month.
Can I do something like this?

```
      month=`date +'%m' -d 'last month'`

 java -DCONFIG_DIR=... com.example.myapp.grades.gradingProcess $1 $month
```

And when I run my script, it'll be something like this: ./myscript.sh 'John'
and not pass in a two-digit month since I'm already doing it inside the script?

Or is that not the correct way to go about it?
Sorry if this seems like an elementary question, I'm still trying to get used to bash scripts.

Thank you?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  One suggestion: if a person's name can have a space in it, you'll want to put `$1` in double quotes so it gets passed as a single token.  (The user will also have to use double quotes.)

Comment: @JuanTomas -- Not just *if* you expect spaces; if you do proper quoting even when you don't expect to need it, you'll avoid bugs when your expectations were incorrect. (I've actually seen a massive data loss event after someone chose not to quote a variable expansion that was expected to only contain filenames matching `[0-9a-f]{24}` -- a buffer overflow dumped a string containing a whitespace-surrounded asterisk into a name, a poorly-written script tried to delete that file, and calamity ensued).

Comment: @JuanTomas, so I don't need to put $month in quotes, correct? 
Also, I know for a fact that I will only be passing in one word names (no spaces), but thanks for the heads up! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: You should basically quote everywhere unless you know why not. See also [When to wrap quotes around a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for how to supply a default value in the shell, there is an operator for that.

```
month=${2-$(date -d 'last month' +%m)}

java -stuff "$1" "$month"
```

Now, if there was a value in `$2`, `month` will be set to that; otherwise, the default will be used.  The notation `${variable-value}` supplies the value of `variable` or, if it is unset, the text `value`.  (There is also `${variable:-value}` which produces `value` if `variable` is set but empty as well.)

(This could be inlined into the `java` command line, even, though using a variable to break it up is probably better for legibility.

```
java -stuff "$1" "${2-$(date -d 'last month' +%m)}"
```

Notice also how you basically always put user-supplied variables in double quotes.)

Comment: month=${2-$(date -d 'last month' +%m)}
Why do I need the 2 in this variable?

Comment: If `$2` is set, `month=$2`.  If `$2` is not set, `month=$(date -d 'last month' +%m)`.  I tried to explain this in the answer; is it not clear?

Comment: Oh oops, just saw that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts: time zone, leading zero, and leveraging Java rather than bash.

## Time zone

Determining the current month requires a current date. Determining the current date requires a time zone.

For any given moment the date varies around the globe. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal.

When you do not specify a time zone, a current default time zone is implicitly applied. Be aware that the default can change at any moment. And depending on the default means your code is relying on an externality outside your direct control. And it means results will vary.

So around the ending/beginning of the month you could be getting the wrong month number determining on the time zone in play.

## Leading zero can mean octal in Java

The `%m` you are using produces two digits. Single digit month numbers will have a leading zero. Ex: `09`

Be aware that in some situations in Java a number with a leading zero is interpreted as a [octal number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) rather than a decimal number (base 10).

## Let Java do the work

I suggest it makes more sense to let the Java class do the work of determining the previous month. The bash line should be passing the desired/expected time zone rather than the month, if anything.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
int previousMonthNumber = LocalDate.now( zoneId ).minusMonths( 1 ).getMonthValue() ;
```

Tip: In Java, even better to use an object from the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum rather than a mere integer. Makes your code more self-documenting, type-safe, and guarantees valid values.

```
Month month = LocalDate.now( zoneId ).minusMonths( 1 ).getMonth() ;
```

Comment: It is trivial to specify a time zone for the `date` command; just set `TZ` in the command line. (Eg. `TZ=America/Lima date +%-m -d'last month'`).

Comment: It's overtly dramatic to say "the default can change at any moment". If you are running a shell, the environment is created before the shell initializes, and will stay put until the shell exits.  If the admin changes the global default settings in the meantime, you will only notice when you start a new shell.

Comment: My point is that implicitly relying on the default time zone has two risks: (a) it is an externality outside of your control (a fact, not overly dramatic when it can completely change your results), and (b) many programmers do not know or think about time zone in general and even less so with determining a month.